# Ending several phrases in a list with a dangling preposition

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, sentence-meaning

> Purchaser will provide for payment in full to the Supplier ***upon the delivery*** to, ***third party inspection of*** and acceptance for shipping at the port of entry of all Products required by said CPO or CPO’s,***the loading on board of all Products***, issuance of an on-board bill of lading and fulfillment without limitation of all conditions for payment established in the CPO or CPO’s and by the Financial Institution of the Purchaser,

Could you help me to explain this paragraph?

1. > upon the delivery to,

   To where? (which word or phase in the paragraph is used to make a supplementary to it?)
2. > third party inspection of

   Of what? (which word or phase in the paragraph is used to make a supplementary to it?)
3. > the loading on board of all Products.

   What's the subject of this sentence in this paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have spotted, this sentence is badly garbled. It looks to me like the writer

- started to compose this section as a series of phrases ending in *to*, with *port of entry* as the object of all the *tos*, and then
- switched in midstream to a series of phrases ending in *of*, with *Products required by said CPO or CPO's* as the object all the *ofs*

—and never got around to sorting out the consequent mess.

It is also possible that the writer created the text by adapting an existing FOB contract and failed to make some necessary changes.

Anyway -- Now that we've established that this is a CFI contract, I ***think*** that the document is intended to describe a situation in which the Supplier is responsible for

a) getting the Products CFI (that is, at Supplier's cost), to a destination "port of entry", and then
b) getting the Products inspected and accepted by a third-party carrier, and loaded onto that carrier's vessel or traincars or trucks for delivery (at Purchaser's cost) to Purchaser.

The passage as a whole defines what hoops the Supplier has to jump through in order to get paid. The basic provision is

> Purchaser will provide for payment in full to the Supplier

Everything after this point is a preposition phrase telling *when* payment is to be made; I've filled in the elements which have been deleted and/or postponed:

> upon
>   1. the delivery <sup>of the Products</sup> to <sup>the port of entry</sup>
>   2. third party inspection <sup>of the Products</sup> <sup>at the port of entry</sup>
>   3. and <sup>third party</sup> acceptance <sup>of the Products</sup> for shipping at the port of entry
>
> > *the products in question being specified as* 
> >     Products required by said CPO or CPO’s,
>
> 4. the loading on board <sup>the third party carrier's vehicle</sup> of all Products,
> 5. issuance <sup>by the carrier</sup> of an on-board bill of lading
> 6. and fulfillment <sup>by Supplier</sup> without limitation of all conditions for payment
>
>    > *those conditions being specified as*
>    >     established
>    >
>    > > (a) in the CPO or CPO’s, and 
>    > >       (b) by the Financial Institution of the Purchaser,

*Purchaser* is the subject of the sentence.

The figure you ask about, with the prepositions left "dangling" to wait for their postponed object, is called Right Node Raising (don't ask why, it's not worth knowing). It's very popular with lawyers and other bureaucrats who think difficult syntax demonstrates their sophistication. Few even of these semiliterates abuse the figure quite so grotesquely as this writer does; but at its best RNR is a graceless, pompous device which is quite out of place in any register.

Comment: who execute "fulfillment without limitation of all conditions for payment". it's the Financial Institution of the Purchaser, right? thanks

Comment: No. The 'fulfillment' is 'executed' by Supplier; the conditions are established by a) the CPO and b) Purchaser's bank. The contract is talking about a Letter of Credit: Purchaser arranges a line of credit with a prime bank at Supplier's end, the bank promises Supplier that payment will be made, Supplier provides the bank documentation that all the contract conditions have been met, Purchaser instructs the bank to pay Supplier, Supplier endorses the Bill of Lading to the bank, and the bank turns it over to Purchaser so he can claim the shipment when it arrives at his end.

Comment: thanks my friend. another "and acceptance for shipping at the port of entry of " execute by the "third party inspection " OR Purchaser? thanks

Comment: third party inspection then acceptance for shipping at the port of entry ?right?thanks

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense, but the wording does not stipulate a sequence, it just lists the conditions that must be met.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Port of entry is odd; in my world the import license is Purchaser's responsibility, and I suspect it is an error for port of shipment. But I'm only familiar with FOB contracts, and this could be a CIF. I've marked this with '[?]' ... Note, too, that I have corrected my own error--I should not have written 'delivery to Supplier' but, tentatively, 'delivery to port of shipment'.

Comment: @StoneyB thanks, what's the subject of " acceptance for shipping at the port of entry of " it's "third party".  right?  why?

Comment: @tom It gets tricky here, because I'm not confident what sort of contract is being described. As I said, in FOB contracts this makes no sense. If I'm right that what is intended is "acceptance at the shipping port", then it is *probably* the master of the vessel who accepts the cargo; I suppose it could be the inspecting authority, but *accept* is odd  in that context: I would expect *clearance* or *release*. I'd need more contract details to be sure.

Comment: @StoneyB yes,it's for CIF. you are right.

Comment: @tom Aha! That explains a lot -- more than you might expect. I'm going to put that into the answer (and it would be helpful to future readers if you put that into the question, too), and rewrite to explain what I think is going on here.

Comment: @StoneyB great.many thanks.i am waiting for your full detail  answer

Comment: @tom you got it

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to parse this:

> Purchaser will provide for payment in full to the Supplier upon
>
> - the delivery to,
>
>   third party inspection of
>
>   and acceptance for shipping at the port of entry of
>
>   all Products required by said CPO or CPO’s,
> - the loading on board of all Products,
> - issuance of an on-board bill of lading
> - and fulfillment
>     without limitation
>
>   of all conditions for payment
>
>   established in the CPO or CPO’s and by the Financial Institution of the Purchaser,

There is an error in this, because "delivery to" and "shipping at" are both trying to point to "the port of entry", but "third party inspection of" and "port of entry of" both want to point to "all Products required by said CPO or CPO’s". I'm guessing that "third party inspection" was added in later, after the sentence had already been constructed, because it works with that phrase removed.